# Get number of MongoDB connections with C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb

How to get the number of (open) MongoDB connections with the C# driver (1.9.0 NuGet package)?
MongoDB documentations describes that db.serverStatus() should give iformation about the count of open and available connections but I can't find any function in the C# driver which represents this information.
(Documentation of db.serverStatus(): http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/ )

Comment: You can refer to the content here.
[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54201705/mongo-c-sharp-json-reader-was-expecting-a-value-but-found-replsetgetstatus)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I searched my fork of the driver for serverStatus, there's no results, so currently, I don't think this command is supported.

There's no associated jira (with serverStatus, at least) that [i can find](https://jira.mongodb.org/issues/?jql=project%20=%20CSHARP%20AND%20text%20~%20serverStatus)

Adding this functionality would be fairly trivial I would think

**Edit**

I wrote on the mongodb driver google group, and got this reply from Craig at MongoDB inc.

> You can simply run:
>
> MongoDatabase adminDb = ...;
>
> adminDb.RunCommand("serverStatus");
>
> I believe this needs to be run on the admin database.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort! This was really what I was looking for.